# Memory management of large lists in Python

Tags: python, list, memory-management

Today I wrote a program using an array/list with 64000000 entries. However, when writing `sigma=[1]*64000000` using Python it runs fine, but later on, as the program computes, my Ubuntu freezes - without any reaction to inputs, not even mouse movement. I tried twice and the results are the same.

When implemented in C++, `long long sigma[64000000]` holds up fine and runs very fast.

Is there any reason that my program would freeze in the middle of running, other than crashes at beginning?

EDIT: To reply to Chris below, my code did not freeze until a couple of loops later.

Thank you all!

For those who interested in seeing the code, this is the program, a brute-force Project Euler 211:

```
def e211():
ans=0
sigma=[1]*64000000
for i in range(2,64000000):
    j=i;
    if ((j%1000==0) or (j<100)):
        print(j)
    q=i*i
    while j<64000000:
        sigma[j]+=q
        j+=i
for i in range(1,64000000):
    j=int(sqrt(sigma[i]))
    if j*j==sigma[i]:
        ans+=i
if __name__=='__main__':
    print(e211())
```

Comment: You allocated a 500MB array on the stack in C++?

Comment: Which version of python are you using ?

Comment: @Nicholas Well that's daily meal for contest programmers:)

Comment: @Ziyao Wei, on a side note, How many have you solved so far ?

Comment: @Pavan Up until now, 164. Working towards the next level:) How about you?

Comment: @Ziyao, 72 :( Wish I had more time though. I only get to work on it once a month or so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python lists are lists of *objects*. A number in Python is an object in itself, and takes up somewhat more storage than the 64 bits needed to represent a `long long` in C++. In particular, Python transparently handles numbers larger than 32 bits, which end up taking a *lot* more space than a simple integer.

You may be find the standard Python [`array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module useful. It provides Python-compatible access to uniform arrays of integers of specified size. (However, I note that it doesn't offer a 64-bit integer type.)

Comment: So this happens maybe because Python changes the sizes of the int variables during the run so the memory dried up? THX:)

Comment: I dont want to sound like an idiot, but "standard Python array module" ? I thought numeric arrays were something unique to numpy. But then again I googled it myself and found this http://docs.python.org/library/array.html. Only to find the entry points to be ridiculous :D somehow array([1,2,3],'l') seems more easy than array('l',[1,2,3])..

Answer (score 2):

```
range(1,64000000):
```

This line creates a full list of size 64000000, so now you have two lists of that size in memory. Use `xrange` instead.

Comment: Thanks! This is something new to a Python newbie like me. However, my program did not freeze until the 49th and 97th loop, respectively:)

Comment: The behavior of range is different from python 2.7 to python 3.2. range in python 3.2 is an extended version of xrange from 2.7.

Comment: Ah but there's no way it can be python 3 if I put my fingers in my ears and shout "my old code will always work! Lalalalala!"

Comment: My code indeed is coded in Python 3. Is there any idea how to improve this using the new version's feature?

Comment: @Ziyao: just stay the course. Pavan is right, Python 3's range doesn't create a full list in memory, that was a python 2 thing. I'd listen to Greg if I were you.